# DocuSign API - Responsive Signing

Tags: docusignapi

I'm working on an integration with the DocuSign API, currently testing it out in the Sandbox. I was looking to add support for [Responsive Signing](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/converting-pdf/) and decided to test this out on a mobile device first before I added the `htmlDefinition` object to the `documents` object to see how a sample document appears currently on a mobile device.

When I viewed the document in my iPhone it already showed the responsive version automatically without me having to make any changes:

[image]

I'm now wondering if I need to bother making any changes if this happens automatically, but I can't find any documentation to indicate that this is now an automatic setting.

There seems to be no difference between sending a request like this:

```
    "documents" : 
[
    {
        "documentBase64" : "JVBEROA0KJSVFT0Y=",
        "documentId" : "1",
        "name" : "Agreement.pdf"
    }
]
```

and sending a request with the htmlDefinition object like this:

```
    "documents" : 
[
    {
        "documentBase64" : "JVBEROA0KJSVFT0Y=",
        "documentId" : "1",
        "htmlDefinition" : 
        {
            "showMobileOptimizedToggle" : false,
            "source" : "document"
        },
        "name" : "Agreement.pdf"
    }
]
```

In my Sandbox settings I do have the option for `Allow recipients to view mobile-friendly documents with responsive signing` enabled, so I'm wondering if that is enough and that will automatically enable Responsive Signing on all envelopes that I send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature you're using automatically convert everything you send to DocuSign into HTML for "mobile friendly" view. It's not the full feature set of responsive signing.
Responsive Signing, the term, suggest just that it works nicely on mobile, but it does more than that. It allows you to, for example, use HTML markup to determine where signing elements (tabs) would show in the document.

If all you need is the ability to make things mobile friendly, looking good on mobile devices, you're all set, you don't have to send responsive HTML to DocuSign.